# Strange behavior in if constexpr() in C++

Tags: c++, c++20

The code below can be used to find number of members in a struct.

This code works

```
struct UniversalType {
    template<typename T>
    operator T() {
        return T{};
    }
};

template <typename T>
consteval auto MemberCounter(auto ...Members)
{
    if constexpr (requires { T{ Members... }; } == false) {
        return sizeof...(Members) - 1;
    }
    else {
        return MemberCounter<T>(Members..., UniversalType{});
    }
}
```

But this code does not work:

```
template <typename T>
consteval auto MemberCounter(auto ...Members)
{
    if constexpr (requires { T{ Members... }; } == false) {
        return sizeof...(Members) - 1;
    }
    return MemberCounter<T>(Members..., UniversalType{});
}
```

Only difference between them is that the second one does not have an else block.

Error message:

```
main.cpp:24:28: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use ‘-ftemplate-depth=’ to increase the maximum)
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Without that last return being in an else, if the constexpr is true the compiler effectively sees `return sizeof...(Members) - 1; return MemberCounter<T>(Members..., UniversalType{});` and the second return, even if not reached, still needs to compile.